# Can't open Microsoft Teams' files tab

Tags: firefox, chrome, microsoft-teams

When I try to open the file tab in any team in Microsoft Teams, it won't load. For the application and Chromium browser, it says: `There was a problem reaching this app` and for Firefox it says: `Something went wrong PrefetchFailure (RenderListDataAsStream (NoConnection))`.

As far as I know, this applies only to the file tab and nothing else.

(File tab refers to MS Teams > Teams > (any team) > (any channel) > Files)

I am using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

That very much sounds like a problem with the server, or with the software trying to reach something that isn't there on the server.

In both cases, there's nothing you can do but file a support case with Microsoft. Teams doesn't have the best track record in fixing bugs in the web clients quickly, so you might just not be able to use this functionality very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error `PrefetchFailure (16)` when opening the Teams file tab in Chrome. As discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftTeams/comments/13l98bw/prefetch_failure_16/), the problem could be resolved by unblocking third-party cookies, e.g., by clicking on the padlock in the address bar -> Cookies and site data -> Disable Block third-party cookies

[image]